# regex split and filter construction

Tags: c#, regex

I need to filter input, to get only string inside parenthesis: *Test1, Test2, Test3*. I have try, but it is not working.

```
 string input = "test test test @T(Test1)  sample text @T(Test2) Something else @T(Test3) ";
 string pattern = @"[@]";
 string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple match instead.

```
(?<=@T\().*?(?=\))

string strRegex = @"(?<=@T\().*?(?=\))";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"test test test @T(Test1)  sample text @T(Test2) Something else @T(Test3) ";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
   if (myMatch.Success)
   {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use something such as `@T\((.+?)\)`?

Comment: @npinti added.With lookarounds only required part will be available.

Comment: Yes, npinti has a point: look-arounds with lazy matching impact regex matching performance greatly.

Comment: @stribizhev: My question wasn't really much about performance, but rather what does the expression in this answer do more than the one I provided in the comment. I mean, why not go for the simple design?

Comment: @npinti cos there you will have to grab the group but here the answer is straightaway...:P

Comment: @npinti: Here, regex performance and "design" (or "syntax", etc) go hand in hand. I prefer to use capturing groups where they are meant to be used, and look-arounds if we need to get overlapping matches, or check for presence or absence of some patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `@"[@]"` regex pattern matches a single `@` character anywhere inside an input string. When you split against it, you are bound to get more than you need.

You should be matching rather than splitting:

```
string input = "test test test @T(Test1)  sample text @T(Test2) Something else @T(Test3) ";
string pattern = @"@T\((?<val>[^()]*)\)";
string[] substrings = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
           .Cast<Match>()
           .Select(p => p.Groups["val"].Value)
           .ToArray();
```

[image]

The `@T\((?<val>[^()]*)\)`  regex will match:

- `@T` - literal `@T`
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `(?<val>[^()]*)` - (Group with "val" name) 0 or more characters other than `(` or `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`

Comment: That solution is also awsome! Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Just note that `.*?` does not match a newline (with `RegexOptions.None` suggested by vks), and a negated character class used in my suggestion does. And my regex is much more robust (if we are to compare them using regexhero.net service)